# Count every elements inside an iFrame with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, casperjs

I am searching for a way to count every element inside a div. The problem is, the div is inside an iFrame.

```
casper.then(function() {
        this.echo(this.evaluate(function() {
             __utils__.getElementByXPath('//*[@id="main-frame"]', __utils__.findAll('#design-scrollbox-0')).length;
        }));
    });
```

What I trying to do above is:

- Getting the iFrame with XPath
- Collecting every element
- and finally getting the length of the returned array.

I'd love if you could point my in the right direction. Sadly, I cannot use a jQuery version > 1.7, so jQuery.contents is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could inject some other jQuery version, but you don't need it, since CasperJS provides a convenient way of changing into the iframe and doing stuff in its context. [`casper.withFrame`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#withframe) is a shortcut for the PhantomJS functions `page.switchToChildFrame` and `page.switchToParentFrame`. It creates a new step from the callback where further steps can be nested.

There are certainly different types to count elements, but probably the easiest is using

```
casper.getElementsInfo(selector).length
```

This is the function for printing the number of links I use for the proofs-of-concept:

```
function printLinks(){
    try{
        this.echo("elements: " + this.getElementsInfo("a").length);
    } catch(e) {
        this.echo("CAUGHT: " + e);
    }
}
```

Proof-of-concept for **i**frames:

```
casper.start("http://jsfiddle.net/anjw2gnr/1/")
    .then(printLinks)
    .withFrame(0, printLinks)
    //.withFrame(1, printLinks)
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Done', this.getCurrentUrl());
    })
    .run();
```

prints

```
elements: 33
elements: 2
```

Proof-of-concept for frames:

```
casper.start("https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html")
    .then(printLinks)
    .withFrame(0, printLinks)
    .withFrame(1, printLinks)
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Done', this.getCurrentUrl());
    })
    .run();
```

prints

```
CAUGHT: CasperError: Cannot get information from a: no elements found.
elements: 210
elements: 4024
```

So, if you want to count elements, but don't want to use a try-catch block, this is better:

```
casper.exists(selector) ? casper.getElementsInfo(selector).length : 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Casper's switchToChildFrame (see for example [this link](http://www.acnenomor.com/4698603p1/how-do-i-access-an-iframe-from-casperjs)) to get 'into' the iframe.

(untested):

```
casper.then(function() {
    // switch the context to first child frame
    this.page.switchToChildFrame(0);

    // ... execute casper commands in iframe context

    // and switch back to parent frame if you need to
    this.page.switchToParentFrame();

    // ... execute casper commands in parent page context
});
```

To count elements you could try (untested also):

```
casper.then(function() {
    var amount_elements = this.evaluate(function() {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#design-scrollbox-0");
        // you can store in the DOM:
        window.amount_elements = elements.length;
        // and return the amount
        return elements.length;
    });
});
// the object stored in the DOM can be used later on:
casper.then(function() {
    var amount_elements = this.evaluate(function() {
        return window.amount_elements;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this `$('ul').children().length` this will tell you all the children element in the selector. Hope it helps.